# Why does it say that flask is not installed but after running flask --version i see that 'Flask 2.0.2' is the current version?

Tags: python

Running python3.7.3 on debian linux env 64bit.
Following along this article `https://realpython.com/python-web-applications/`

These are the steps following up to the error

1. `$ python3 -m venv ven`
2. `$ source venv/bin/activate`
3. `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. `python3 main.py`

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

the files

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: python3
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==2.0.2
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return"Congratulations, it's a web page!"

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

here is the github link `https://github.com/codyalvarez/hello-app`

something this simple should be so difficult to get going haha.
cheers

just an edit that may lead to clues - when i run

`FLASK_APP=main.py flask run`

my program works fine ?

Comment: When running `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, don't you get warnings that some directory which you are installing things are not on PATH, or something similar?

Comment: nope, it installs fine

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to restart your pc? Often when you install a new pip library you need to either restart your IDE/Code editor or your entire PC. Also, check if you're using the right python interpreter

Comment: Never had to do this.